# Can't access Solr admin. But admin/cores works

Tags: solr

I use solr 3.5.0

When I can retrieve information from `http://localhost:8070/select/?start=0&q=product..` and see my cores from `http://localhost:8070/admin/cores` but I can't access `http://localhost:8070/solr/admin` tried some number of combinations to access admin panel.

my solr.xml

```
<cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
    <core name="base"    instanceDir="base" />
</cores>
```

and solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/admin/" class="org.apache.solr.handler.admin.AdminHandlers" />
  <admin>
    <defaultQuery>solr</defaultQuery>
  </admin>
```

Seems like solr can't find handlers to admin page, but of course I have all the solr handler classes in my dependencies list.

Comment: Try accessing `http://localhost:8070/solr/<corename>/admin` ?

Comment: `http://localhost:8070/solr/base/admin/` same as before.

Comment: `corecontainer.getManagementPath()` returns null..
`corecontainer.getAdminPath()` == 'admin/cores' should it?